# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: string, python-2.7, object, attributeerror

```
class System:
    def __init__(self,code,name,price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.code = code

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Code: ' + self.code + '\tName: '  self.name + \'tPrice: ' + self.price 

    def choose_item(self):
        count = 0
        for item in self.name:
            print str(count) + '\t' item.name + '\t' + item.cost
            count += 1
        question = raw_input('Enter the code: ')
        if question == 0:
            exit()
        elif choice != self.code:
            print 'Invalid code'
        else:
            index = question -1
        name[index].self.choose_item()
        print 'Your item has been added'
```

I got this error and can't see the mistake. I want to choose items by keying the code so that the item will be added. Not sure is this the correct way to do.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: Do not change the original code. keep it with errors otherwise whoever go through this will be confused with the answer provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two errors are in this function `__str__(self)`
It should be `'\tName: ' + self.name + '\tPrice: '` 
(You have missed `+` sign and have not included \t inside single quote.)

```
return 'Code: ' + self.code + '\tName: ' + self.name + '\tPrice: ' + self.price
```

Then in `choose_item(self)` function. (Missing + sign)

```
print str(count) + '\t' + item.name + '\t' + item.cost
```

Comment: Thank you @ MarlonAbeykoon  I've changed the code and still give me the same error. Any suggestion to fix the code?

Comment: @Beginner is it working? if so accept the answer by clicking on the tick.